# Redis Pod with 3 replica and Persistence Storage not providing data all the time

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I have created Persistence Volume, Persistence Volume Claim and used the same for Redis Deployment with 3 replicas (YAML shared below)

It allows me to set and get the data.

However POD1 is not able to fetch data set by POD2 and vice-a-versa

I want to fix this issue so that POD1-POD2-POD3 can exchange the data from same PV

redis-pv-volume.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: redis-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/home/dev/redis_data"
```

redis-pv-claim.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: redis-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

Here is my deployment file
redis_deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: redis
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: redis-data-store
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: redis-pv-claim
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/data"
          name: redis-data-store
```

And Services for CLusterIP & NodePort for external use

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - targetPort: 6379
      port: 6379
      nodePort: 30379
  selector:
    name: redis
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-cluster-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - targetPort: 6379
      port: 6379
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: redis
```

All the data is getting stored on my local storage but pods are not able to fetch the data with GET KEY command for values SET by other PODS

For Ex
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, here you are missing the concept of **Redis** clustering and networking.

Just starting the 3 replicas won't resolve your issue, and they won't interact with each other.

What you are trying to do is replication or clustering across the PODs.

**Second issue :**

You have mentioned

```
accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
```

in PVC and PV due to this your all PODs cannot be attached to single PV or PVC.

You have to use the `ReadWriteMany` or services like **NFS** or **EFS** to create PV, PVC and attach single PV, PVC behind all PODs.

**Third issue :**

> Redis Pod with 3 replicas and Persistence Storage not providing data
> all the time

You are just running the image without any type of backup or snapshot configuration

```
- name: redis
  image: redis
```

Start AOF & RDB

```
image: redislabs/redis
args: ["--requirepass", "admin", "--appendonly", "yes", "--save", "900", "1", "--save", "30", "2"]
```

Redis support 2 types of backup support to persiste the data.

**AOF & RDB** you can read more at : https://redis.io/topics/persistence

**Final answer :**

Instead of trying to configure the Redis and Replication, i would suggest using the **Helm** chart which will create the Statefulsets and **PVC** by own without doing many configurations and you can run the **HA Redis cluster** with persistence **data**.

Helm chart link : https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/deploy-redis-sentinel-production-cluster/

Chart YAML : https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis

This is the Redis HA cluster with **sentinel** configuration.

Read more about the sentinel at :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70271427/5525824
- https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis#master-replicas-with-sentinel

Comment: Hi Harsh, Implementing ReadWriteMany  does not resolves the problem and tried with new image params suggested by you but still same. I was looking for option without helm by creating common storage and multiple redis instance from k8s can read/write from same storage providing feel of cluster where as all all nodes will be master redis

Comment: i never said it will work. i just suggested you can use param for the backup proposal. now just changing the image or RWX will never work in your case as you are planning to use RWX so you might have to do other extra configurations like each POD save to different folder but using same backup folder etc. if you are planning to use redis cluster like multiple master checkout : https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis-cluster

Comment: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/1514 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58463237/kubernetes-nfs-pv-lock-questions